# remove "search icon" from select2.min.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, jquery-select2

I am using select2 js library to make my selectbox as searchable. But its showing a search icon on the select2 as well (when expands). I want to hide this "search icon". The image is attached.
Note: I used the same library in other project and it was not showing the search icon.
I would be grateful if anybody help me to remove the search icon. Thanks
[image]

The Code is written here:

```js
$('#BchId').select2();
```

```html
<div>
<select asp-for="BchId" class="form-control" name="BchId" data-parsley-required="true" data-parsley-trigger="change" data-parsley-errors-container="#branch-error" placeholder="Branch"
                                            asp-items="@(@ViewBag.BranchList)">
<option value="">@Resources.PleaseSelectBranch</option>
</select>
<span id="branch-error"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Use your f12 browser debugger to pinpoint where the image/icon is coming from. I'm not sure I've seen this with select2.

Comment: I have checked but not getting any clue, as its not showing in the debugger

Comment: I suppose that was passed from your Html property. I don't see any icon from my application of using select2

Comment: and... ur code? How I can help u without your code?

Comment: @YaelMassieu I have added the code, please have a look

Comment: I tried to check the sample code shared by you. When I run it did not produce any result as you are binding the data with it. Could you please try to create a sample using the static data which we could use to run the code to check the issue? If there is any CSS code please also include it. it may be related to your own code. I refer to the Select2 docs and I did not see any information on it. Ref: [Select2 Search](https://select2.org/searching).